# Javascript in place of json input step

Tags: json, mongodb, pentaho, kettle, e4x

I am loading data from a mongodb collection to a mysql table through Kettle transformation.
First I extract them using MongodbInput and then I use json input step.
But since json input step has very low performance, I wanted to replace it with a
javacript script.
I am a beginner in Javascript and even though i tried somethings, the kettle javascript script is not recognizing any keywords.

can anyone give me sample code to convert Json data to different columns using javascript?

Comment: _"I am a beginner in Java"_ - Java and JavaScript are unrelated languages. Can you perhaps show some of the code that you have so far?

Comment: ok I dont know either of them

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to see three aspects:

1. Reading from MongoDB
2. Reading from JSON
3. Reading from (probably) String

**Reading from MongoDB** Except if you changed the interface, MongoDB returns not JSON but BSON files (~binary JSON). You need to see the MongoDB documentation about reading and writing BSON: probably something like `BSON.to()` and `BSON.from()` but I don't know it by heart.

**Reading from JSON** Once you have your BSON in JSON format, you can read it using `JSON.stringify()` which returns a `String`.

**Reading from (probably) String** If you want to use the capabilities of JSON (why else would you use JSON?), you also want to use `JSON.parse()` which returns a JSON object.

My experience is that to send a JSON object from one step to the other, using a `String` is not a bad idea, i.e. at the end of a JavaScript step, you write your JSON object to a `String` and at the beginning of the next JavaScript step (can be further down the stream) you parse it back to JSON to work with it.

I hope this answers your question.

*PS: writing JavaScript steps requires you to learn JavaScript. You don't have to be a master, but the basics are required. There is no way around it.*

Comment: Thank you everyone for inputs .. I would try to learn javascript and try it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the **json input step** to get the values of this json and put in common rows

Comment: Guess this will not help me , because I do not want output in json format and more over both json input and output steps are very slow.So I need to write a javascript to speed up the process.

Comment: use the json input step as NOT FINAL step. I mean, you use this step and now you have rows that you can process normally with other steps. I dont get the concept "output steps are very slow". I use this steps daily without noticing worst performance than javascript steps.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake, i mean json INPUT step